# Django Templates - generate and save XML file by chunks (to save RAM)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

We generate sometimes huge **XML** files in the `Django` project and these files are then saved to the `FileField`. Since those files are **XMLs** sometimes built from tens or hundreds of thousands of projects, it consumes a lot of **RAM**. Is it possible to generate the files by chunks?

```
@classmethod
def from_eshop(cls, eshop):
    content = mark_safe(render_to_string(template_path, context={'products': some_queryset}))
    ramfile = ContentFile(content)
    att = ExportFileGenerateAttempt.objects.create(eshop=eshop)
    att.file.save(utils.files.generate_filename(eshop.name,True),ramfile)
    return att
```

Comment: You're generating the XML by rendering an XML "template" with Django template tags in it? If the answer to that is yes - are you using any conditionals or looping constructs in the template?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes I do, there are loops and conditions too. Those templates are patterns for import XLMs to ecommerces.

Comment: Could you split the template into chunks? 1 template for the "head", 1 template for each "project" and then 1 template for the "footer", you could then write the file in chunks  (head -> project -> project -> ... -> footer)

Comment: @IainShelvington Maybe yes, I'm afraid this is the only way to do that. I hoped for some built-in solution.